# How to Remove duplicate Arrays (by id) while Grouping?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

sample data:

```
 [ {_id:5,job:"a",exp:1,
    tech : [ 
         "ERP Systems SAP R/3 ECC6.0", 
         "Operating Systems", 
         "Microsoft Dos"
          ]
     }]
```

I have 3 people data (in 6 rows (after flattening)).Based on "_id" i am taking unique values in pie grpah (every slice count is 1).but failed to do same in row chart(with commented lines).How do i get only unique id's "tech" and give it to "1st row chart"(presently in 1st row chart every technology has count 2 .i want to remove duplicates based on _id).

how to group technologies (only one time for 1 id ignore remaining)?

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/7s5vr6fj/1/)

any suggestions .Thanks in Advance

Comment: Basically, you need to track ids you've already seen, and the number of each id you've already seen. Then increment those count of the id when you get a new one, decrement when you remove one, and remove the id from the list of previously seen ids when the count goes to zero. Only increment your actual counter when you see an id you haven't seen before. That's complicated, and is one of the reasons I wrote Reductio, which handles this using exception aggregation: https://github.com/esjewett/reductio#exception-aggregation

Comment: Thanks for the reply @EthanJewett can you please  provide any example?

Comment: Thanks @EthanJewett (i didn't use reductio . but did what you said )

Comment: Cool, glad it worked, and sorry I didn't give an example. Didn't have time at the time, which is why I left a comment not an answer :-(

Comment: Hi @EthanJewett can you please provide some example using reductio .because i am facing performance issue(with another approach).

Comment: The link to Reductio documentation includes an example of doing count & sum aggregation over d.bar. You would just need to modify the example slightly to aggregate over d._id instead (e.g. `.exception(function(d) { return d.bar; })`). https://github.com/esjewett/reductio#exception-aggregation

Comment: hi @EthanJewett                                                                                         var dim = data.dimension(function(d) { return d.exp; }); var group = dim.group();    var reducer = reductio()
    .exception(function(d) { return d._id; })    .exceptionCount(true);
reducer(group);  i'm able to get count for Pie graph By using above.But "how do i do it for row graph if you see in fiddle i'm using custom reduction's".can you please tell me how to use for row chart?

Comment: Hi @sandeep - why are you using custom reductions? It looks like you are just counting unique values per id, right? That's just what Reductio's exception aggregation should be doing.

Comment: Oh, I see. Scratch that. You are using a groupAll because you have multiple technologies per record? You'll need to use Reductio's groupAll() method and then you can define an exception aggregation. That should work. I will answer below with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the conversation in comments, to accomplish the groupAll aggregation on technology with Reductio, you would want to:

```
var techGroup = tech.groupAll()
var reducer = reductio()
  .groupAll(function(d) { return d.tech; })
  .exception(function(d) { return d._id; })
  .exceptionCount(true);

reducer(techGroup);
```

This is a use-case that is not very well-tested at the moment (using groupAll with exception aggregation). It should work and there are some basic tests for it, but I'm afraid I'm making you into a bit of a guinea pig here. Please let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hi @Ethan Jewett Sorry for the late reply.i implemented your suggestion.it is working but it is taking more time than the regular approach.

Comment: Hi sandeep - I'd be happy to look at an example and see if there are any optimizations that I can make in Reductio. Generally speaking, groupAll is probably just be less efficient than an approach of creating multiple records and using the standard group. But it's doing something inherently different, so that is to be expected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply  @Ethan Jewett .i will share  example as soon as possible